# Postman test - reusable body request (body as variable?)

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I'm pretty new to automation tests and using Postman.

I have a collection of tests that send the same request body with smaller variables - I have found out how to use pre-request script to make smaller changes to the body for test purposes. For test reasons I have to keep the test in seperate requests.
So far so good.
What I really want to do is to be able to have ONE body (like a reusable body) If they (devs) add a new required field - I would NOT have to change 20-25 bodies in different tests. So ONE body so when devs changes the make-up of the API I have ONE place to change my body.

I hope this makes sense.

I have tried to create a parameter for this purpose but that does not seem to work.

Comment: My body is relatively simple {
 "method": "post",
 "url": "http://www.testme.com/api/run/test"
 } /b If set the body as a variable in the environment it says "Implicit body inferred for parameter "request" but no body was provided. I set it as a string I set it as "{
 "method": "post",
 "url": "http://www.testme.com/api/run/test"
 }" and just use {{body}} in the body on the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a JSON body, and not form data.

You can save the body as an JSON string in an environment or collection variable, then you can do the following in a pre-request script.

```
const body = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("body"));
// make any changes to the body here
pm.request.body.raw = body;
// console.log(pm.request.body.raw);
```

If you don't need to make any changes to the body, you can just reference the variable like following...

[image]

Comment: There are a few assumptions with this answer, which would ideally be clarified if you included a screenshot of your existing request to ensure we have the correct context.

Comment: I know this is semantics, but you have a collection of "requests" which may have tests in the tests tab.  If you are sending the same request then I'm pretty sure you could define your test data in an array, and then loop the request using setNextRequest instead of having 25 identical requests.  Also what do you mean by "smaller variables".